# Regular expression pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, match, filenames

Please I need help accomplishing the following:

I have a number of files like the following in an array:

```
jack+0.txt
jack+2.txt
jack+4.txt
tim+0.txt
tim+2.txt
tim+4.txt
raph+0.txt
raph+2.txt
raph+4.txt
wells+0.txt
wells+2.txt
wells+4.txt
etc.
```

I want to write a program to do the following:

```
if the filename is like *0.txt, a++;
if the filename is like *2.txt, b++;
if the filename is like *4.txt, c++;
```

The core help needed is in using the regular expression (in Java).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying out the methods suggested and will be back shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.getName().matches(".*0[.]txt") {
        a++;
    } else if ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, and Daniel, my hats off.  This idea works for me.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

The idea, if you have a small amount of different ending:

```
if (filename.endsWith("0.txt")) a++;
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

I would just do a String split on the plus sign, and check the second part.

```
String[] parts = s.split("+");
if (parts[1].equals("0.txt") {

} else // the rest of the tests
```

Answer (score 0):

This wil take the number out of the filename and then you can do a switch case

```
string filename;

int category = Integer.parseInt(filename.substring(filename.length() - 5, filename.length() - 4))
```

Comment: What if the files have more than one number in the future?